# JavaFx Printing a node without displaying it

Tags: javafx, printing

I have a TableView where each row represents a record and I have a view button beside it which creates a new view displayed in a tab with details the record and with a print button. If I hit the print everything works fine.

Now I want to add a print button to the table view row, which does create the record view and prints it but without displaying it in a new tab. The not opening in a new tab is crucial as I later will add a print all and print selected button.

The problem is, that when I want to print it without adding it to a tab an empty page gets printed.

How can I print something without displaying it?

Comment: I don't have any trouble printing a `Node` that is not part of a scene, even if it's a `Control` (and skin may not have been initialized)... Please create a [mcve].

Comment: I think you can create what you want to print without ever adding it to the `Scene`. Then just print it. This is just a guess. Follow fabian advice.